# Вопросы по печати средствами Java2D

Tags: java, печать, java2d

Изучаю вывод на печать средствами Java2D. Есть два вопроса к знатокам:
1. Есть ли возможность форматирования текста в методе g.drawString() с помощью html-тегов, как при создании JButton и JLabel?
2. Мне нужно кроме печати на принтер организовать сохранение документа. Для начала хотя бы просто в txt-формате либо в формате jpg-картинки. Откуда начать копать реализацию этой задачи?
Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

у Java 2D довольно скромные возможности в этом плане. Касаемо форматирования, есть возможность изменять шрифт и стиль:

```
int style = Font.BOLD | Font.ITALIC;
Font font = new Font ("Arial", style , 11);
graphics.setFont(font);
graphics.drawString("Hello world!", 100, 100);
```

По поводу сохранения документа, можно сделать скриншот программы и сохранить полученное изображение в файла, например так:

```
private static void saveToFile(JFrame frame) {
    BufferedImage bImg = new BufferedImage(frame.getWidth(), frame.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    Graphics2D graphics = bImg.createGraphics();
    frame.paintAll(graphics);
    try {
        ImageIO.write(bImg, "png", new File(FILE_NAME));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Или создать объект Graphics2D из BufferedImage, нарисовать на нем элементы и сохранить.

Comment: Об использовании setFont(), setColor() и т.д. я в курсе. Хотелось облегчить себе жизнь :) Просто стоит задача вывода табличного документа на печать. С HTML-ом всё было бы намного проще. А по поводу сохранения скриншотом, интересно. Надо это покурить. Спасибо.

Comment: А почему именно java 2d? Мне кажется можно найти сторонее решение с большими возможностями по форматированию.

Comment: О сторонних решениях  я слышал. Но хочу попробовать самому. В конце концов главная задача - обучение java.

Answer (score 1):

В общем, откопал одну статью на javatalks: http://javatalks.ru/topics/22127?page=1#155982. Оставлю здесь, может кому пригодится. Пока это лучшее решение, которое я находил. Буду курить в этом направлении.